# Can I read data faster from Cassandra using Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am using cassandra database and I have a python script for reading data from cassandra database. Script is doing well. I wonder this if I use spark, can I read data faster from Cassandra ( using cql )?

Comment: What do you want to do with that data?

Comment: Just reading with filtering some fields after that i am gonna write to csv.

Comment: I would recommend to look to DSBulk that is heavily optimized for data offload

Answer (score 0):

Yes definitely,  spark is made processing huge amount of data , but if the data is less you will not gain anything than to take more time to read.

Comment: I have a spark cluster type of standalone so which parameters are important for me ? Because in my configuration i could not gain speed. Cassandra read speeds and spark read speed so close now.

Comment: 1st you have to design your database correctly as per your requirement and also have to try 
https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/reference.md

parameters.

Comment: Actually i checked this page. If you have configuration about this parameters, can you share ?